# Java Turning a negative number into -1 and a positive number into 1

Tags: java, math, double

I've seen other posts like this but not in java. I want to convert a negative double like  -6.9 and turn it into -1.0 or if its 4.2 turn it into 1.0 . I can do it with a bunch of if statements but id like to use a cleaner way.

Comment: There are the cases of `0.0, -0.0, inf, -inf, +NAN, -NAN`.  Interesting to know what results are desired then.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is exactly what `java.util.Math`'s [`signum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Math.html#signum-double-) method does. Note that it returns a `double`, so you may want to cast it to an `int`:

```
int result = (int) Math.signum(someNumber);
```

**EDIT:**
The body of the question and the title slightly contradict each other, and after re-reading the question I'm not sure if you want to get `int`s of `1`/`-1` or `double`s of `1.0`/`-1.0`.
If it's the former, the above answer should do the trick. If it's the latter, you should remove the explicit cast to `int`, and just use `signum`'s return value:

```
double result = Math.signum(someNumber);
```

Comment: just note that it returns `0.0` when input is `0.0` (case not specified in question) ((and it will return `float` for `float` parameter))